# como puedo utilizar JSON_SET sin corregir todo el registro - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

Tengo un problema con unos objetos json

Pasa que tengo la siguiente estructura

```
obj = {items:[...],references:[{id:1},{name:"a"}]}
```

El problema surge cuando estoy procesando el objeto, trato de actualizar un valor en referencia, por ejemplo, quiero actualizar "id" por 5

```
JSON_SET(obj ,'$references[0].id', 5);
```

Pero me sale error de que el json_set no esta en la posición correcta, intente con un select, pero aunque hace bien el cambio, solo lo muestra y en el objeto no se ve el cambo y queda con el valor inicial.

No puedo actualizar el registro en la tabla de la BD, solo necesito cambiarlo mientras lo proceso.

Conocen alguna forma en la que pueda corregir este error ?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Además, `JSON_SET` como su nombre lo indica, es para cambiar valores, si lo que quieres es extraer valores, [debes usar una función específica para ello](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html). Si no encuentras ahí la forma de hacerlo, por favor explica mejor el problema indicando el error que estás recibiendo. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pregunta no es del todo clara, sin embargo, una opción para insertar o actualizar datos en documentos JSON es la función [`JSON_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set) (la documentación está en inglés).

El problema está en la sintaxis del argumento `path` de la función [`JSON_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set), necesita cambiar `$references[0].id` por `$.references[0].id`, ejemplo:

```sql
SET @`obj` := JSON_SET(@`obj`, '$.references[0].id', 5);
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f923f2e17e5d873f8bed55155bb6c32).

Comment: Lamento no haber explicado correctamente mi problema, pero gracias por entender, tu solución fue la correcta y funcionó perfecto para lo que necesitaba, GRACIAS